# Excel macro to hide lines based upon whether a value in col a exists in an array of cells on another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet (Sheet1)  that contains hundreds of names in col a.  If a certain value exists in cell Q3 of sheet1, I need to search an array of columns and rows (A5:J55) on a separate worksheet (Sheet2) consisting of 200 or more names and if the name in each row in col a is not found in the array, hide the row. The array to be searched and the worksheet it is found on will change each time the value in cell Q3 is changed, so there would be a sequence of "If" conditions. (I have a macro to unhide all rows.)

Comment: Sounds like a problem that could be solved by an advanced filter

Comment: I don't see how a filter would work, because the row to be hid is the row on a line in sheet 1 that has a name in col. a, but that name is not found on worksheet 2.  I think it could use the find (value) routine for each name in column a of sheet 1, and if not found on sheet 2, hide that line on sheet 1. My knowledge of VBS is just too limited for me to put the necessary code together.

Comment: You just set up an Advanced Filter rule (using a formula) that returns `True` if the name on Sheet1 is not found on Sheet2.  If you want it to be dynamic, you could set up an event-triggered macro to re-run the filter on changes in `Q3`.  Read about using formulas as criteria in the Advanced Filter.

Comment: "if the name in each row in col a is not found in the array, hide the row" <--- this refers to sheet1 or 2 ?

Comment: "If the name in each row in col a is not found in the array (which is the entire sheet2), hide the row" refers to sheet1.  Example: if sheet 1, column a, row 9 contains the name "Charles" and sheet 2 does not contain the name "Charles", row 9 should be hidden on sheet 1, then go to the next row and check for the name "c

Comment: then go to the next row and check for the name "c  .. ?